# Couldn't convert pytorch model to ONNX

Tags: python, pytorch, transfer-learning, onnx, onnxruntime

I used this repo : https://github.com/Turoad/lanedet
to convert a pytorch model that use mobilenetv2 as backbone To ONNX but I didn't succeeded.

i got a Runtime error that says:

> RuntimeError: Exporting the operator eye to ONNX opset version 12 is
> not supported. Please open a bug to request ONNX export support for
> the missing operator.

it's really disappointing, looking to the good result that this model gives and the quick performance that it provides,

is there any way that I can fix this bug? because I need to convert it to ONNX and then to TF lite model to use it in Android App
I will provide the pretrained model that I have used and the way that I follow in converting..

Thank you so much for helping!

my colab notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18udIh8tNJvti7jKmR4jRaRO-oYDgRmvA?usp=sharing

the pretrained model that I use:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o3-BgLIQesurIyDCKGliqbo2inUA5cPw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow: users might downvote or ignore the question in its current format. Please see how to ask questions:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use torch>=1.7.0 to convert the model, because operation [Eye](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e85d494707b835c12165976b8442af54b9afcb26/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset9.py#L1648) is added.

Comment: Thanks! it worked when I used the latest version available on colab but I got a cuda runtime error sadly!

Comment: > RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.